# Existence of one-one map from uncountable set to countable (infinite) set.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

1. There exist uncountable many disjoint intervals of type (r1, r2) where r1, r2 are non-equal real numbers?
2. As between any two real numbers there is a rational number, there exist one-one map from above interval to set of rational numbers?
3. So, for existence of one-one map from set A to set B what matter is, are they infinite sets or not, don't matter is they're uncountable or countable?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: All three are questions.

Comment: Please limit yourself to one question per post. It's fine to ask potential follow-up in advance, but in that case it is good to add some context around those follow-ups. And please make sure there's context to your question.

Comment: But they are related.

Comment: Then explain how. That's called context.

Comment: Second question is about the intervals whose existence is questioned in first. Third is about a conclusion someone may have it first two are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, there are not. Precisely because you can't have more of such intervals than rational numbers.
2. There are many such maps, since you have infinitely many rationals in each interval.
3. It does matter. If you have a bijection between two infinite sets, they must have the same cardinality, either both countable or uncountable.

Comment: But why there can't be uncountable many such intervals.

Comment: Because if you have a one-to-one mapping from $A$ to $B$, then the cardinality of $A$ is necessarily less than or equal to that of $B$. In your case, $A$ is the set of disjoint intervals and $B=\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I'm confused here, if first statement is false then how second is true and how second can be used to disprove first.

Comment: To every interval in your set of disjoint intervals you can attach some rational number belonging to it. Therefore, there are as many intervals as corresponding rational numbers you chose. But the set of {\bf all} rational numbers is countable, so a subset can be only countable.

Comment: "There can't be any injection from uncountable set to countable set." Can you please point me to some proof of that.

Comment: If you have an injection from $A$ to $B$, you have a bijection between $A$ and its image inside $B$. By definition of cardinality, this image has the same cardinality than $A$. In particular, if $A$ is uncountable, the image would be uncountable. In your case, your B$ is the set of rational numbers, which is countable and, as such, cannot contain an uncountable subset.

Comment: OK, thanks very much sir. I get it now.

Answer (score 1):

> If there is an injection from $A$ to $B$, then $|A| \le |B|$, where $|\cdot|$ denotes cardinality. This is basic set theory. A dual fact: if there is a surjection from $A$ onto $B$, then $|B| \le |A|$.

For every interval $I=(r_1,r_2)$ we can pick a $q(I) \in \mathbb{Q} \cap I$ by denseness of $\Bbb Q$.

Then $I \to q(I)$ is injective by disjointness. So the *set of disjoint  intervals* has cardinality at most $|\Bbb Q|$, i.e. countable.